# ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided authorization was invalid in ios

Tags: ios

I have integrate Braintree Payment gateway in my App but it have Some error like 'ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided authorization was invalid' I don't for how to solve this please help me for solve the error.

I post the code here..

```
-(void)Show_payment{

self.braintreeClient = [[BTAPIClient alloc] initWithAuthorization:_clientToken];



BTDropInViewController *dropInViewController = [[BTDropInViewController alloc]
                                                initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];




dropInViewController.delegate = self;

// Or, upon initialization
dropInViewController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];


BTPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [[BTPaymentRequest alloc] init];
paymentRequest.callToActionText = @"Connect";


dropInViewController.paymentRequest = paymentRequest;




// This is where you might want to customize your view controller (see below)

// The way you present your BTDropInViewController instance is up to you.
// In this example, we wrap it in a new, modally-presented navigation controller:
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(userDidCancelPayment)];

dropInViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:dropInViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Comment: are you fix this issue?

Comment: yes I fixed it..@sathya